# Hibernate Composite Primary Key Issue while Saving entity Object

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am trying to save entity using hibernate, But somehow not able to see the record in database table, there is no exception is generated.

My Table, Class and hbm.xml file mapping are as follow.

Table : Table has composite primary key as id and mobile columns.

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `mobile` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `name` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`mobile`)
);
```

Classes :

```
public class StudentPk implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private String mobile;

    public StudentPk() {
        super();
    }

    public StudentPk(Integer id, String mobile) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }

    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((mobile == null) ? 0 : mobile.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        StudentPk other = (StudentPk) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (mobile == null) {
            if (other.mobile != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!mobile.equals(other.mobile))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


}


class Student{
    private StudentPk pk;
    private String name;

    --getter-setter-

}
```

Hibernate Mapping :

```
<class name="com.Student" table="student" proxy="com.Student">
   <composite-id name="id" class="com.StudentPk" >
        <key-property name="id" type="java.lang.Integer" column ="id"/>
        <key-property name="mobile" type="string" column ="mobile"  />
    </composite-id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string" />
</class>
```

I have also map this hbm.xml file in hibernate.cfg.xml file too.

Please help me for this.

Answer (score 2):

The are few rules you have to keep in mind when writing Primary key class:

1. The primary key class must be public and must have a public no-arg constructor.
2. The primary key class must be serializable.
3. The primary key class must define equals and hashCode methods.

Comment: Hi, I have add the equals and hashcode method but still not able to save, I have added the equals and hashcode method in above question.

Comment: You have added to Student class, I think it should be added to StudentPk class. Also you will need to implement Serializable.

Comment: Hi,I have added the complete class, but still same problem

Comment: I have checked for Select and It is working without any issue, I don't know why Insert is not working

Comment: Could you post your code for hibernate where you're performing insert?

Comment: **Thanks Rahul**, Now I got the issue, In My application I have return one method which always get new Session so at last it call new session and try to persist using that new session while Actual object is available in another session.

Comment: Glad to here that. I actually had thought the same, it must be issue with hibernate session, hence asked you for the Hibernate code.

Comment: Hi Rahul, when I do the Session.save(obj), so the auto_increment column value is not back fill in obj instance, any idea ?

Comment: Yes it is, If I change it to simple Id in hibernate then it is working